# UITableView reload data when click button

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I want to reload the data from uitableview when I press the button.

example: 
if I press button 1, then I will present data with id 1, and if I press the button 2 then I will present data with id 2 and previous data are not shown.

Anyone know how, I use [tableview reloadData]; not working, change happens if I move the screen and return to the screen that displays the data in the tableview?

Thank's before.

Comment: You should change the data in your array before reloading the tableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow This link, perhaps it will help you.

[stackoverflow.com/questions/7290340/xcode-tableview-showing-to-different-arrays-one-at-a-time-problem](http://xcode-tableview-showing-to-different-arrays-one-at-a-time-problem)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

if fired when u click the button simply write this also

```
-(IBAaction) buttonclick
{
   [self.tableView reloadData];
   // your code...
}
```

Comment: I have seen your code, but in cellForRowAtIndexPath how you are checking that which table to load.. I mean how you are getting whether button 1 is selected or button 2 ?

Comment: the difference lies in the variable message whose data comes from a query that vary according to press my buttons.

[[[self AppDelegate] chatDB] closeLog];
[[[self AppDelegate] chatDB] getChat: buddyName: YES];

This is the code to refresh the data in the variable message

Answer (score 0):

You should not create UILabel *labelMessage; and other variables each time your application calls tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. Instead try to do this with all your variables:

```
if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UILabel *labelMessage;
        labelMessage = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        labelMessage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        labelMessage.tag = 5;
        labelMessage.numberOfLines = 0;
        labelMessage.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        labelMessage.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        labelMessage.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
        labelMessage.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        labelMessage.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        labelMessage.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:136.00/255.00 green:91.00/255.00 blue:14.00/255.00 alpha:1.0];

        UIView *message = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
        [message addSubview:labelMessage];
}
UILabel *labelMessage = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
/* Set textMessage value here */
labelMessage.text = textMessage;
return cell;
```